# One Keyboard Key Not Functioning

Tags: keyboard

Few weeks ago I noticed that the 'p' key was not functioning normally. Since then I have had to press the key progressively harder for a 'p' to appear on the screen. Now it has stopped working. The last attempts (last 2 days), I pressed the key so hard that it could potentially have broken the keyboard.

I am now using the on-screen virtual keyboard to typppppppppppppppppppppppppe the 'ppppppppppppppppp' but this is exactly what happpppppppppppppppppppppppens when I click only once(!!) on the virtual keyboard's 'pppppppppppppppppppp' key.  Maybe this strange result is a clue to the cause of the ppppppppppppproblem ?

PLEASE HELP

Comment: Your hardware key is probably broken. You may 1. change the keyboard of your device if it is possible or create a custom keyboard layout mapping another less used key (example: [) to type 'p' instead.

Comment: Laptop keyboard or external and how connected?  Keyboard will likely need to be fixed or replaced, for now maybe disconnect.  Can use google to get instructions for your computer.

Comment: Laptop keyboard is integrated, non-removal....

Comment: Dear To Do.  Where can I find instructions how to do this? To map the 'broken key' to another less used key ?  Thanks.

Comment: Google your laptop.  Most keyboards have a connection inside.  Your 'P' key might be partial jammed now.   Add an external keyboard.  Will be surprise how easy it is to fix some laptops yourself.  Google can find your laptop and instructions to do most repairs.